# Inserting Image from hard disk into SQL Server in while loop

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, bulkinsert, varbinarymax

I have some photos in specific drive on a hard disk, these photos all have a `*.jpg` extension and  numeric name.

For example : `1.jpg , 2.jpg ,  5.jpg , ...`

I'm trying to insert these photos into a table with this schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Employees
(
    Id int NOT NULL,
    Photo varbinary(max)NULL
)
```

At first step, I don't know what's wrong with this :

```
DECLARE @i INT
SET @i = 1
WHILE (@i <=100)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Employees (Id, Photo) 
            SELECT @i,  BulkColumn 
            FROM Openrowset( Bulk 'C:\Pictures\'+convert(nvarchar(5),@i)+'.jpg', Single_Blob) as EmployeePicture
            SET @i = @i + 1
    END
GO
```

Because I get an error:

> Incorrect syntax near '+'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'data_file' argument of OPENROWSET(BULK ... ) must be a quoted string literal, it cannot be a variable or an expression. You'll have to use dynamic sql, I fear.

```
DECLARE @i INT
SET @i = 1
WHILE (@i <=100)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
    SELECT @SQL = 'INSERT INTO Employees (Id, Photo)
        SELECT ' + convert(nvarchar(5), @i) + ', BulkColumn FROM OpenRowSet ( Bulk ''C:\Pictures\' +
        convert(nvarchar(5), @i) + '.jpg'', Single_Blob) as EmployeePicture'

    exec (@SQL)

    SET @i = @i + 1
END
GO
```